# extracting an element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Assume this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1171 [product_id] => 140 [fileid] => 479717 [purchid] => 847 [cartid] => 833 [uniqueid] => f100c3b3a853202fb6559fbacf025a6aa07f52c7 [downloads] => 99998 [ip_number] => [active] => 1 [datetime] => 2015-06-02 20:10:05 )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 1172 [product_id] => 140 [fileid] => 313624 [purchid] => 847 [cartid] => 833 [uniqueid] => f00a3c91378ad469f333abeec64753b275f10670 [downloads] => 99999 [ip_number] => [active] => 1 [datetime] => 2015-06-02 20:10:05 )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 1173 [product_id] => 140 [fileid] => 313618 [purchid] => 847 [cartid] => 833 [uniqueid] => ac125595e2dbca6a086261434582f6e7dfc5638e [downloads] => 99999 [ip_number] => [active] => 1 [datetime] => 2015-06-02 20:10:05 )
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 1174 [product_id] => 140 [fileid] => 313526 [purchid] => 847 [cartid] => 833 [uniqueid] => 3e6123e0a4453de71dec91a177f5b34217625680 [downloads] => 99999 [ip_number] => [active] => 1 [datetime] => 2015-06-02 20:10:05 ))
```

I want to "extract" the [0] array and use it for something else BUT it has to be conditioned.

I said the 0 element because it has the fileid = 479717 the one that i want.

So i`m looking at extracting the array (in my case [0]) that has filed = $myvalue. Where i can set $myvalue to whatever i want.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us your code.

Comment: My code is based on running a foreach of the original array ($products) and then doing another SQL query to extract just the "array" that i need again from the database but it will be an overkill

Comment: @misulicus maybe you need to improve your first SQL query and add some conditions? Give us more details.

Comment: use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - [here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AlU4yS)

Comment: Though a duplicate, that is 6 years old.  I guess we add an answer to the old one to make it up to date?  Also, those are needlessly complex nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fits your needs ?

```
function findById($id, $arrayOfArrays){
    foreach ( $arrayOfArrays as $contents ) 
        if ( $contents['id'] == $id ) return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter($fileid, array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['fileid'] === $fileid) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```